# div runat server onclick without postback handle on backend

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm using an Update Panel in which I have a div which I made as runat server. I want to add the onclick event to the div. I could see some suggestions from StackOverflow with postback options. Since, I'm using update panel, I do not want the whole page to get loaded again. Is there any way to achieve this?

My ASPX Code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
            <div runat="server" id="mydiv" onclick="mydiv_click">
            </div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My Code Behind content:

```
Sub mydiv_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   //my function definitions here
End Sub
```

Comment: May be you should look at Ajax?

Comment: With a DIV, onclick is a client side trigger. You need OnServerClick and the DIV html element does not support that. Why are you trying to use a DIV? What are you trying to accomplish? You could try wrapping your div with an ANCHOR (A), runat="server" and use onserverclick for that.

Comment: @Daved: I'm learning this stuff. I can do all the stuff with asp elements for the events. I can give styles for the div elements on the backend when using runat server. But I cannot add an event listener to the div inside the updatepanel without postback.

Comment: A DIV cannot have a serverclick event handler and that's what you need to trigger the function in your VB code. You can, however, set "onserverclick" for an anchor element (A) that is runat="server" and you can wrap DIVs with As, validly, as of HTML5.

Comment: The way you say works fine Daved. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Just in case you weren't sure what I was referring to, I added an answer for you with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a DIV, onCLick is a client side trigger. You need OnServerClick in order to trigger a server side click event. While there may be a better approach depending on what you are trying to accomplish, take this example as one way to accomplish the same effect, though using an anchor element, instead of the div, to handle the "onserverclick".

ASPX:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="scripman1" />
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="update1" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <a href="#" runat="server" id="somewrapper" onserverclick="somewrapper_ServerClick">
            <div runat="server" id="something">
                Something here
            </div>
        </a>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

VB code:

```
Protected Sub somewrapper_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    something.InnerText = "This is another test of mine."
End Sub
```

The end result of this should be the text in the DIV changing without a full page post.